# how can i use table partition and row level secrity on tables together in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, row-level-security

I want to partition a table and then use row level security on those table to grant access to application users.Partition is based on organisation id and as such and is dynamic.

Comment: Please Google it.